# python tkinter textbox console output to be always in last line?

Tags: python, tkinter, console, textbox, stdout

I have this textbox:

```
t_outputbox = tk.Text(tab_console, width=99, height=18, font='Tahoma 12',bg='#051da3', fg='#d9d9d9', relief="flat", highlightthickness=1, borderwidth=1)
```

And use a function to print all console output to it:

```
def redirector(inputStr): # send all prints to GUI instead of console
t_outputbox.config(state=NORMAL)
t_outputbox.insert(INSERT, inputStr)
t_outputbox.see(END)
t_outputbox.config(state=DISABLED)
```

And use this commadn at the ned of my code to activate stdout to use redirector() to write.

But sometimes, when I click into my console, and scroll up and down, it does print in the middle somewehere and not at the end of the textbox.

Is there a fix for that so that new prints are forced to always beat the end of the box?

```
sys.stdout.write=redirector
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because you are inserting text after the position of `INSERT`. Here, `INSERT` means the position of cursor. If you want to insert text at the end of the text widget then you need to replace `INSERT` with `END`

```
def redirector(inputStr): # send all prints to GUI instead of console
    t_outputbox.config(state=NORMAL)
    t_outputbox.insert(END, inputStr)
    t_outputbox.see(END)
    t_outputbox.config(state=DISABLED)
```